# RoboGuice injection in a Service started by a widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, roboguice

Could anyone provide any pointers on how to perform injection in a Service using *RoboGuice 1.1.2*.

I use a Service to poll a server every so often. The service populates the database of my app with some data from the server response. The service is started from the `onUpdate` method of an `AppWidgetProvider`.

It updates the application using an instance of a POJO that has some variables which are instantiated via injection using the RoboGuice framework. I need then to inject the POJO in my Service.

Is there some way of doing this or do I need to change my approach? Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Thats sounds more like message passing since you are going from one Context, the widget, to another, the Service.  I typically wouldn't use roboguice for this type of injection.  I have never worked with a widget and provider but I usually just use simple data serialization with [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) extra data and / or [Parceable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and [Bundles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I agree that I'm probably taking the wrong approach! Leaving this open for now as I would still like to know the actual mechanics of how to inject something in a Service.